# Referenced class library not found when using cdk with C# to deploy .NET 8 projects

Tags: c#, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, .net-8.0

I have a .NET based lambda function `LambdaProjectFunction.csproj` and class library `LambdaProjectLibrary.csproj` that is referenced in the `LambdaProjectFunction` project.

Both projects are in the following folder structure

```
C:\dev\testproj1\apps\func-code\src\LambdaProjectLibrary\LambdaProjectLibrary.csproj
C:\dev\testproj1\apps\func-code\src\LambdaProjectFunction\LambdaProjectFunction.csproj
C:\dev\testproj1\apps\func-code\src\lambda.sln
```

The cdk project is the path as below

```
C:\dev\testproj1\infra\src\infra.sln
C:\dev\testproj1\infra\src\infra\infra.csproj
```

This is the relevant code in the infra stack also written in C#

```
var buildOption = new BundlingOptions()
        {
            Image = Runtime.DOTNET_8.BundlingImage,
            User = "root",
            OutputType = BundlingOutput.ARCHIVED,
            Command = new string[]{
           "/bin/sh",
            "-c",
            " dotnet tool install -g Amazon.Lambda.Tools"+
            " && dotnet build"+
            " && dotnet lambda package --output-package /asset-output/function.zip"
            }
        };

var function = new Function(this, "LambdaFunc", new FunctionProps {
            Runtime = Runtime.DOTNET_8,
            Code = Code.FromAsset("../apps/func-code/src", new Amazon.CDK.AWS.S3.Assets.AssetOptions //folder pointing to the solution's location.
            {
                Bundling = buildOption
            }),
                           
        });
```

When running cdk synth, I get this shown in the console

```
Bundling asset testproj1-InfraStack/LambdaFunc/Code/Stage...
Skipping NuGet package signature verification.
MSBuild version 17.9.4+90725d08d for .NET
  Determining projects to restore...
  Restored /asset-input/LambdaProjectLibrary/LambdaProjectLibrary.csproj (in 173 ms).
  Restored /asset-input/LambdaProjectFunction/LambdaProjectFunction.csproj (in 7.84 sec).
  
 LambdaProjectLibrary -> /asset-input/LambdaProjectLibrary/bin/Debug/net8.0/LambdaProjectLibrary.dll
  LambdaProjectFunction -> /asset-input/LambdaProjectFunction/bin/Debug/net8.0/LambdaProjectFunction.dll

Build succeeded.

Time Elapsed 00:00:30.48
Amazon Lambda Tools for .NET Core applications (5.10.2)
Project Home: https://github.com/aws/aws-extensions-for-dotnet-cli, https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet

No .NET project found in directory /asset-input to build.
Unhandled exception. System.Exception: Failed to bundle asset ...
.
.
.
```

If I remove the reference to the `LambdaProjectLibrary` then it synths and deploys. The problem is only when a project reference `LambdaProjectLibrary` is added to the main function project `LambdaProjectFunction`

Even though my build succeeds why isn't it getting dropped in the `asset-input` folder thereby causing the overall deploy to fail and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else in a similar situation. You need to point your code assets to the project root where you can get all your projects pulled in, so this stays as is `Code = Code.FromAsset("../apps/func-code/src",`

You need to also modify the package command to as it is below
--project-location

```
dotnet lambda package --project-location lambdaFuncProject/ --output-package /asset-output/function.zip
```